# ¿Porque mi proyecto en java no me deja insertar datos en mysql, aunque no me aparece ningun error?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

```
  private void GuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

     try {
    conexion c =new conexion();

    Statement s= c.con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT * from cliente");
    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO cliente (Cod_Cliente, Nombre_Cliente,Numero_Mesa)Values(´"+CodigoCliente.getText()+"´,´"+NombreCliente.getText()+"´,´"+Mesa.getText()+"´)");
     }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
     {
     System.out.print("Error"+e);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Que lenguaje estas usando?  Cambia las `\`` por `'`

Comment: Me deje llevar por el primer comentario sin edita, gracias

Comment: Te funciono cambiar las comillas?

Comment: Si, gracias por la ayuda, era lo único que me faltaba para casi concluir mi proyecto de la preparatoria

Comment: De nada y bienvenida al foro.

Comment: El código de inserción es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría el siguiente cambio:

```
try {
    conexion c =new conexion();

    Statement s= c.con.createStatement();
    // ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT * from cliente");
    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO cliente (Cod_Cliente, Nombre_Cliente,Numero_Mesa)Values('"+CodigoCliente.getText()+"','"+NombreCliente.getText()+"','"+Mesa.getText()+"')");
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    System.out.print("Error"+e);
}
```

Te aconsejo colocar las clases con Mayúsculas por estándar. O sea la clase conexion debiese llamarse Conexion. también cambié las ` por '. Saludos!